# Xamarin IOS: How to display a popup control from button click

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

This is for iPhone.

I have a button and when it's clicked I want to pop-up another control which covers the whole screen. This screen could have any number of controls. And I can close this screen by clicking on an x in the top right corner or programmatically inside any event on the new screen.

I could probably do this by using a UINavigationController which just brings me to a new screen and has a link back to the previous screen but I would just like to ask if there is another option?

What I am doing is I have a map which shows a users location from a pin. But if the user wants to type in a new location instead of using the pin location then they will click a button, go to a new screen, type in an address and click a "suggested" address from what they type.

Any advice would be appreciated or a link to a code sample would be great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use popover for iPhone, I think that you can use Modal View.

```
yourButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
    YourController yourController = new YourController();

    yourController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
    this.PresentViewController(yourController, true, null);
};
```

And to close you only need to dismiss the modal.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect!!

I used UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext instead of UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet.

Comment: I need to send data back to YourController to MyController. I have a call back event when DismisModelView completion handler. At this point of time MyController all object become null. Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

If it's an iPad app you can use [UIPopoverController](http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/Popovers/).

```
// myvc is an instance of the view controller you want to display in the popup
UIPopoverController pop = new UIPopoverController(myvc);

// target is another view that the popover will be "anchored" to
pop.PresentFromRect(target.Bounds, target, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
```

If it's an iPhone app you can't use UIPopoverController.  If you just want a small input box with a single button, you can use UIAlertView (this works for iPhone and iPad)

```
UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView();
alert.Title = "Title";
alert.AddButton("OK");
alert.Message = "Please Enter a Value.";
alert.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;
alert.Clicked += (object s, UIButtonEventArgs ev) => {
  // handle click event here
  // user input will be in alert.GetTextField(0).Text;
};

alert.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am using iPhone. The UIAlertView isn't quite what I am looking for. I have updated the question. If you can have another look I'd really appreciate it. Cheers

Comment: the look at using a custom view that is presented modally, like Ricard suggests

Comment: @Jason I tried the code but I am getting an error:   
Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSGenericException Reason: -[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.
Do you know what the reason is?

Comment: try declaring your popover controller as a class level variable so that it does not get picked up prematurely by the GC